# Bulk update for related models

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models:

```
class Model1:
  ...

class Model2:
  ...
  m1 = ForeignKey(Model1)
  var2 = ....

class Model3:
  ...
  m2 = ForeignKey(Model2)
  var3
```

And I'm trying to update Model3:

```
Model1.objects.get(...).model2_set.filter(....).update(... How to update all model3_set__var3? ....???)
```

Comment: I would need some example query to give a good answer. However, as a hint: You want to update `Model3`'s, so ask for `Model3`s and think the other way round: `Model3.objects.filter(m2__..., m2__m1__...).update(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relations:

```
Model3.objects.filter(m2__m2var=1, m2__m1__m1val=1).update(...)
```

`__` is used for relations, and you can use foreign key connections for table joins so you can filter fields on `Model2` by `m2__<m2_field>` and filter fields on `Model1` with `m2__m1__<m1_field>`

[Read the related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Model3.objects.filter(model1__id=x).update(var3=y)
```

I would expect Django to take care of relationships automatically, although I have not tested this across a second level of relationship.

More on that on [Django documentation: Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)